# How to port trial days left when updating a subscription through Stripe customer portal?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

My app offers two subscription plans:

- plan A: 10 €/month, 15 days of free trial
- plan B: 20 €/month, 15 days of free trial

I am using Stripe's [Customer portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal) to let users manage their subscription to my app.
If a user upgrades or downgrades his plan during his trial, the doc says that [the trial ends immediately](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#upgrade-downgrade).
How can I port the trial days left to the new plan?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this within the Customer Portal (which isn't possible) or through Stripe's API in general?

Comment: I am looking for overlooked options, alternatives, or workarounds.